# NPM and Node version being cached when deploying via capistrano

Tags: node.js, npm, capistrano

So I upgrade NPM and Node on our a dev server,

```
user@dev-server:~$ node -v
v6.11.3
user@dev-server:~$ npm -v
5.4.2
```

but when I deploy the app via capistrano it seems that it is seeing the old version of it.

```
(current: {"node":"0.10.46","npm":"2.15.1"})
```

I tried restarting the server but it seems that it didn't work.

I am using the same user when deploying and when I updated NPM and Node.

Is there a cache that I need to clear for it to see the current installed version?

Comment: check the $PATH environment variable to see if capistrano use the correct `node`/`npm` binary. My guess is that you have different version installed on your server. Or use `which node` command in your recipe to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: @GiDo, Thanks for the tip, I was able to update properly the correct `node` / `npm`